# How to calculate time slots with gaps?

Tags: c#

I am developing small appointment application and I need implement method which calculate working hours based on user's input. I got correct time slots example when startWorkingHours = 8 and endWorkingHours = 18

Time slots are: 
[
  "08:00",
  "09:00",
  "10:00",
  "11:00",
  "12:00",
  "13:00",
  "14:00",
  "15:00",
  "16:00",
  "17:00"
]

How can I implement time slots if I add duration of appointment and gap between appointments. Example during appointment 1hour and gap between sessions 0:30 min. In that case time slot need to be:
08:00
09:30
11:00
12:30
14:00
15:30
17:00

First session start 08:00 and takes 1 hours, then break 0:30 minutes and next session start 09:30. How can I achieve this ? This is my code below:

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<string>> CalculateTimeSlots(int startWorkingHours, int endWorkingHours, int durationOfSession, int gapBetweenSessions)
{
    try
    {
        var availableTimeSlots = new List<string>();

        var startDay = DateTime.Today.AddHours(startWorkingHours);
        var endDay = DateTime.Today.AddHours(endWorkingHours);

        var ts = endDay - startDay;
        var hoursBetween = Enumerable.Range(0, (int)ts.TotalHours)
                                     .Select(i => startDay.AddHours(i));

        foreach (var hour in hoursBetween)
        {               
            availableTimeSlots.Add(hour.ToString("t"));
        }

        return await Task.FromResult<IEnumerable<string>>(availableTimeSlots) ;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        _logger.LogError(ex, "Calculate working hours service exception: ");
        throw;
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the problem in using `AddHours(1.5);`?

Comment: yes but I have to always skip first element in array. I think it's not reliable solution.

Comment: Shouldnt this be unit tested just throwing it out their.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a simple `for()` loop with a specific step size (like 60 minutes + 30 minutes) to iterate through all the possible appointment slots:

```
int durationOfSession = 60;
int gapBetweenSessions = 30;
DateTime start = DateTime.Today.AddHours(8);
DateTime end = DateTime.Today.AddHours(18);

for (DateTime appointment = start; appointment < end; appointment = appointment.AddMinutes(durationOfSession + gapBetweenSessions)) {
    Console.WriteLine(appointment.ToString("HH:mm"));
}
```

This will generate the following output:

```
08:00
09:30
11:00
12:30
14:00
15:30
17:00
```

Comment: Thanks @Progman..I forgot on for loop. It works as I expected

Comment: Nice script I need 10 mins slots but I also need to restrict it via opening hours is that what the add hours is doing

Comment: @csharpdude77 The `AddHours()` call is used to generate the time based on the `DateTime.Today` value. This value has the time component set to `00:00:00`. With `AddHours()` and the other methods (like `AddMinutes()`) you can build the `start` and `end` times you need.